# How to add the CSV,PDF buttons for a datatable using the Laravel Yajra plugin?

Tags: laravel

I am creating a datatable using Laravel's Yajra plugin. I am using the query builder form.(Like this [Click here](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/fluent/dt-row))

I wanna add buttons CSV,PDF to the datatable.

I know as per the documentation it can be done [Like this](https://datatables.yajrabox.com/service)

The problem is I have already done using query builder. Now I cannot change my code.

Kindly help me.

My jquery code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('body').addClass('sidebar-collapse');
    var cat = "{{$cat}}";
    $('#unreconcil_datatable').DataTable({
      processing: true,
      serverSide: true,
      ajax: '{!! route('get_datatable',array('cat'=>$cat)) !!}',
     columns: [
            { data: 'unrelines_uniq_num', name: 'unrelines_uniq_num' },
            { data: 'unrelines_bank_accno', name: 'unrelines_bank_accno' },
            { data:'unrelines_rficreated',name:'unrelines_rficreated'},
            { data: 'unrelines_roicreated', name: 'unrelines_roicreated' },
            { data: 'unrelines_bank_name', name: 'unrelines_bank_name' },
            { data: 'unrelines_line_number', name: 'unrelines_line_number' },
            { data: 'unrelines_state_date', name: 'unrelines_state_date' },
            { data: 'unrelines_trans_date', name: 'unrelines_trans_date' },
            { data: 'unrelines_trans_amount', name: 'unrelines_trans_amount' },
            { data: 'unrelines_unrec_amt', name: 'unrelines_unrec_amt' },
            { data: 'unrelines_desc', name: 'unrelines_desc' },
            { data: 'unrelines_variance', name: 'unrelines_variance' },
            { data: 'unrelines_cstatus', name: 'unrelines_cstatus' },
            { data: 'unrelines_assigned', name: 'unrelines_assigned' },
            { data: 'unrelines_created_date', name: 'unrelines_created_date' },
            {data: 'tat', name: 'tat', orderable: false, searchable: false},
            {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
        ]
    });

  });
</script>
```

My controller method is as follows:

```
public function getdatatable($cat){
            $list = AvailableStatementLines::select([DB::raw(" '$cat' AS cat"),'unrelines_id','unrelines_uniq_num','unrelines_bank_accno','unrelines_rficreated','unrelines_roicreated','unrelines_bank_name','unrelines_line_number','unrelines_state_date','unrelines_trans_date','unrelines_trans_amount','unrelines_unrec_amt','unrelines_desc','unrelines_variance','unrelines_cstatus','unrelines_assigned','unrelines_created_date','unrelines_trans_type','unrelines_currency','unrelines_created_by_name','unrelines_ustatus',DB::raw("IF(unrelines_cstatus='closed', '',
                ROUND(ABS(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, date(unrelines_lastupdate), curdate()))/1440 - ABS(DATEDIFF(ADDDATE(curdate(), INTERVAL 1 -DAYOFWEEK(curdate()) DAY), ADDDATE(date(unrelines_lastupdate), INTERVAL 1 -DAYOFWEEK(date(unrelines_lastupdate)) DAY))) / 7 * 2 - (DAYOFWEEK(IF(date(unrelines_lastupdate) < curdate(), date(unrelines_lastupdate), curdate())) = 1) - (DAYOFWEEK(IF(date(unrelines_lastupdate) > curdate(), date(unrelines_lastupdate), curdate())) = 7),0)
                ) AS tat")])->where('unrelines_ucountry',Session::get('country'))->where('unrelines_display',1);

            switch($cat){
                case 'rfi':
                    $list1 = $list->where('unrelines_cstatus','Assigned');
                break;
                case 'roi':
                    $list1 = $list->where('unrelines_cstatus','Solution Provided');
                break;
                case 'closed':
                    $list1 = $list->where('unrelines_cstatus','Closed');
                break;
                default:
                    $list1 = $list->whereNotIn('unrelines_cstatus',['Closed','Assigned','Solution Provided']);
                break;
            }

            return Datatables::of($list1)
            ->addColumn('unrelines_uniq_num',function($list1){
                return "<input type='checkbox' class='uniqnums' name='uniquenum[]' value='".$list1->unrelines_id."'>".$list1->unrelines_uniq_num;
            })
            ->addColumn('action',function($list1){
                return "<button type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-info viewLine'  category=".$list1->cat." unrelines=".$list1->unrelines_id.">View</button>";
            })
            ->setRowClass(function ($list1) {
                return $list1->tat > 7 ? 'orange' : ($list1->tat > 5 ? 'red' : ' ');
            })
            ->make(true);
        }
```

Comment: can you provide code?

Comment: @DharmeshRakholia Kindly check my code

Answer (score 0):

You should apply this method in your controller.

```
public function html()
 {
      return $this->builder()
        ->columns([
            'id',
            'name',
            'email',
           'created_at',
           'updated_at',
        ])
        ->parameters([
          'dom' => 'Bfrtip',
          'buttons' => ['csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print', 'reset', 'reload'],
      ]);
}
```

Comment: Yes @DharmeshRakholia.... I know... The problem is I cant change the code now as I have already created datatables...